# Is the function $f(x)=\frac{2x+y}{2+xy}$ uniformly continuous on $x, y\ge1?$

Tags: calculus, continuity

I have to find if the function $$f(x)=\frac{2x+y}{2+xy}$$ is uniformly continuous on the set $$A = \{(x,y)\mid x\ge1, y\ge1\}.$$

I think that the set $A$ isn't bounded so I can't use Cantor's theorem. Also, $A$ is not open so I can't go with partial derivatives. I was trying to find arrays that will show me that it isn't a uniformly continuous function, but unsuccessfully.

Please, help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: Not a lot.
I think that set A isn't bounded so I can't use Cantor's theorem. Also, A is not open so I can't go with partial derivatives. I was trying to find arrays that will show me that It isn't a uniformly continuous function, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Prove that the partial derivatives are bounded on $A.$

Comment: Ok, I have. What next?
Thank you for editing my post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this particular function the calculations can be performed straightforward, although determining the boundedness of the partial derivatives is more efficient. The function is of the form
$$f(x,y)=2g(x,y)+g(y,x),\quad g(x,y)={x\over 2+xy}$$ It suffices to show  that the function $g(x,y)$ is uniformly continuous on $x,y\ge 1.$ We have
$$|g(x_2,y_2)-g(x_1,y_1)|={|2(x_2-x_1)+x_1x_2(y_1-y_2)|\over (2+x_1y_1)(2+x_2y_2)}\\ 
\le {2\over (2+x_1y_1)(2+x_2y_2)}|x_2-x_1|+{x_1x_2\over (2+x_1y_1)(2+x_2y_2)}|y_2-y_1|\\
\le {1\over 4}|x_2-x_1|+|y_2-y_1|$$ as
$(2+x_1y_1)(2+x_2y_2)\ge 8+ x_1y_1x_2y_2\ge 8+x_1x_2.$
Hence the function satisfies the Lipschitz condition, which implies the uniform continuity.

Comment: Thank you very much!